# Error:Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\mycontroller::cH() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the error as mentioned above in Question here is my method code

```
    function customHeader($id, $user_id, Request $request){

        if ($user_id == Auth::user()->id || Auth::user()->is_admin){

        $method = $request->method();
        // To show View
        if($request->isMethod('GET')){


     }      // Create
     elseif($request->isMethod('POST')){

            // Delete
     } elseif($request->isMethod('Delete')){
                //Delete single

    } else{
            return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Above in function parameters id is required only when user need to Delete records .. i think that error is due that id but i need the id variable. If i remove that $id it works for Create how can i fix that error

Route is as

```
Route::any('/setting/custom-header/{id?}', 'SettingController@customHeader');
```

Comment: why do you need the user_id variable?

Comment: because i have id in url .. if i not use this user can go to others form by edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function customHeader(Request $request, $id, $user_id = null){

        if ($user_id == Auth::user()->id || Auth::user()->is_admin){

        $method = $request->method();
        // To show View
        if($request->isMethod('GET')){


     }      // Create
     elseif($request->isMethod('POST')){

            // Delete
     } elseif($request->isMethod('Delete')){
                //Delete single

    } else{
            return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

change argument order make request as first param and give argument to default value should work.

Comment: dear in this way its no coming in this method  `if ($user_id == Auth::user()->id || Auth::user()->is_admin){///////}`

Comment: if i use this order $user_id, Request $request it goes in it\